# Most efficient way to create collections of objects?

Tags: python, performance, object

What is the most efficient method/data structure to create collections of similar objects in python?

**Example:**

Assume I have a number of `Point()` instances. Each instance has an `x` attribute.

I'd like to group them all together in order to perform bulk operations etc.

I might simply put them all in a list:

```
points = [Point(x=1), Point(4), Point(7)... Point(1)]
```

I could create a class that simply takes this list as input:

```
Class PointCollection():
    
    def __init__(self, points):
        """ points is a list of Point() instances """
        self.points = points
```

In order to access all the `x` attributes, the class might have a method that looks like this:

```
@property
def allX(self): 
    return [pnt.x for pnt in self.points]
```

My question is, is there a better way? I can imagine for a collection of a very large number of points that having attributes that require a loop for access could take some time to compute. In more complex collections you might have a number of attributes, or more deeply nested attributes (a collection of collections?).

Is there a better data structure to implement? Or might it be better to turn to Cython and/or multiprocessing to get more performance?

*EDIT:*

Here is a bit more detail about my specific problem:

This involves some GIS data structures - namely classes which describe river tributaries. A collection of these would describe a river network and I'd be looking at accessing like attributes (like the x coordinates of each tributary, or the 'chainage') for the whole network to perform bulk operations.

However, I would like the 'best' method of creating a very general 'collection' structure, which is why I used the `Point()` example. I can see this being useful in other areas to my work...

Comment: Prematured optimization is the root of all evil :) `timeit` or `cProfile` it. If it really takes too long, then think about other options. List comprehension looks okay, in this case.

Comment: well yes, timeit will tell me how long it takes. But it won't tell me if there is a more efficient method...

Comment: Let's start with the basic fact: Python is not efficient. If you really need more power, use some other language (C++?). But still it might be efficient enough. If you need more CPU, then try multiprocessing. It won't help you if you need more memory to process data though. In that case split the task into smaller tasks and process them one by one. `class` approach seems to be an overhead (simpler is better, i.e. use a list). Unless you intend to use it somewhere else as well.

Comment: Im not asking whether Python is efficient compared to other languages. Im asking if there is a better way of using python for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are mainly dealing with numeric data, consider using NumPy and its [`recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([(1.0, 2.0), (7.3, -1.0), (4.2, 3.7)],
                    dtype=[("x", float), ("y", float)])
>>> b = a.view(numpy.recarray)
>>> b.x
array([ 1. ,  7.3,  4.2])
>>> b[0]
(1.0, 2.0)
```

NumPy provides fairly efficient vectorised operations on array data.

Comment: Thats very interesting and I hadn't thought of it thanks. However, it assumes Im only interested in some numeric attributes rather than a collection of like-objects. Using `Point()` was just an example. I'd like it to be a more general container for a group of class instances.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't cover performance issues, but you can certainly handle such a collection in a more general way:

```
Class PointCollection:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return [point.__getattr__(name) for point in self.points]

    def __setattr__(self, name, values):
        for (point, value) in zip(self.points, values):
             point.__setattr__(name, value)

    def __init__(self, points):
        """ points is a list of Point() instances """
        self.points = points
```

Now you can get/set any attribute directly on the container and it will automatically "redirect" such requests to the contained elements, making your container more flexible in case you want to add/remove attributes.